# Time Machine - Cannot access the personal files I saved

Tags: catalina

I had partitioned my 2TB time capsule with 500GB for backups and remaining for my files under folder 'Personal'. Since yesterday, I cannot see the folder Personal when I look at the Time Capsule under Finder. I only see the sparesbundle file when I open the time capsule now.

Please help.

Comment: Where's your backup of the files in the "Personal" folder?

Comment: Where is the folder Personal?  on your hard drive??